# grab specific field value from the string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I've a text file, from that I have extracted these two paragraph block. The text example is given below:

**Text Example:**

> NOMEAR **ISABELLE FERREIRA ZARONI**, ID FUNCIONAL Nº
> **5100796-7**, para exercer, com validade a contar **de 16 de novembro de 2020**, o cargo em comissão de **Assessor**, símbolo **DAS-7**, da
> **Sub- secretaria de Concessões e Parcerias**, da S**ecretaria de Estado de Planejamento** e Gestão, anteriormente ocupado por
> **Vinicius dos San- tos Silva**, ID Funcional n° **5108029-0**. Processo nº SEI-
> **1 2 0 0 0 1 / 0 1 4 6 11 / 2 0 2 0** .
>
> NOMEAR **KARINE MATOS DIAS**, ID FUNCIONAL Nº **5092869-4** para
> exercer, com validade a contar **de 16 de novembro de 2020**, o cargo
> em comissão de **Assessor**, símbolo **DAS-7**, da **Secretaria de
> Estado de Planejamento** e Gestão, anteriormente ocupado por **Amauri
> Ferrei- ra do Carmo**, ID Funcional nº **5099579-0**. Processo nº SEI-
> **1 2 0 0 0 1 / 0 1 4 6 11 / 2 0 2 0** .

From the above text block I want to grab the **bold** values only from each paragraph as a individual row.

**What I have tried**:

```
filter_data_nomear = ['NOMEAR ISABELLE FERREIRA ZARONI, ID FUNCIONAL Nº\n5100796-7, para exercer, com validade a contar de 16 de novembro\nde 2020, o cargo em comissão de Assessor, símbolo DAS-7, da Sub-\nsecretaria de Concessões e Parcerias, da Secretaria de Estado de\nPlanejamento e Gestão, anteriormente ocupado por Vinicius dos San-\ntos Silva, ID Funcional n° 5108029-0. Processo nº SEI-\n1 2 0 0 0 1 / 0 1 4 6 11 / 2 0 2 0 .', 'NOMEAR KARINE MATOS DIAS, ID FUNCIONAL Nº 5092869-4 para\nexercer, com validade a contar de 16 de novembro de 2020, o cargo\nem comissão de Assessor, símbolo DAS-7, da Secretaria de Estado\nde Planejamento e Gestão, anteriormente ocupado por Amauri Ferrei-\nra do Carmo, ID Funcional nº 5099579-0. Processo nº SEI-\n1 2 0 0 0 1 / 0 1 4 6 11 / 2 0 2 0 .', 'NOMEAR ROSIONE FERNANDES DE SÁ, ID FUNCIONAL Nº\n4413710-9, para exercer, com validade a contar de 16 de novembro\nde 2020, o cargo em comissão de Assistente II, símbolo DAI-6, da\nSecretaria de Estado de Planejamento e Gestão, anteriormente ocu-\npado por Luis Henrique Ferreira de Aquino, ID Funcional nº 1914315-\n0. Processo nº SEI-120001/014825/2020.', 'NOMEAR FRANCISCO DE ASSIS PINTO CAVALCANTE para exer-\ncer, com validade a contar de 16 de novembro de 2020, o cargo em\ncomissão de Assistente II, símbolo DAI-6, da Secretaria de Estado de\nPlanejamento e Gestão, anteriormente ocupado por Edson Carneiro\nda Silva, ID Funcional nº 570136-8. Processo nº SEI-\n120001/014825/2020.']

for i in filter_data_nomear:
    splited_ini = i.split(',')
    splited_ini = list(filter(lambda x: x != 'para exercer', splited_ini))
    splited = [x.strip() \
        .replace("\n",' ') \
        .replace('anteriormente ocupado por ','') \
        .replace('para exercer','') \
        .replace('anteriormente ocupado por ','') \
        .replace('NOMEAR','') \
        .replace('o cargo em comissão de ','') \
        .replace('ID FUNCIONAL Nº ','') \
        .replace('com validade a contar de ','') \ 
        .replace('ID Funcional ','') \
        .replace('Processo nº SEI-','') \
        .replace('símbolo ','') \
        .strip() \
        .replace(u"nº",'--') \ 
        .replace('para exer- cer','') \ 
        .strip() for x in splited_ini]
```

**My Current Output:**

```
['ISABELLE FERREIRA ZARONI', '5100796-7', '16 de novembro de 2020', 'Assessor', 'DAS-7', 'da Sub- secretaria de Concessões e Parcerias', 'da Secretaria de Estado de Planejamento e Gestão', 'Vinicius dos San- tos Silva', 'n° 5108029-0.  1 2 0 0 0 1 / 0 1 4 6 11 / 2 0 2 0 .']
```

My current output is almost ok but having issue with multiple `replace()` and some time this static replace is breaking my code also. So is there other way I can achieve that using regex matching on those bold text?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/wn5moF/3 you can try that regex, not sure if it is good and hence leaving this as a comment, you just have to check for `,` in group 6 when you iterate through the match

Comment: You might use 3 capturing groups to get all the different values `\b(?:(?:NOMEAR|d[ea]|por) ([^,]+?)(?: e Gestão)?,|((?:[A-Z]+|\d+)-\d+)|SEI- ([\d /]+) )` https://regex101.com/r/xN7CYm/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the values in bold, you might use 3 capturing groups with an alternation:

```
\b(?:(?:NOMEAR|d[ea]|por) ([^,]+?)(?: e Gestão)?,|([A-Z\d]+-\d+)|SEI- ([\d /]+)\b)
```

In parts

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent the word being part of a longer word
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:NOMEAR|d[ea]|por)`  Match one of `NOMEAR` `de` `da` `por`
  - `([^,]+?)` Capture **group 1**, match any char except `,` non greedy
  - `(?: e Gestão)?,` Optionally match  `e Gestão` and match a `,`
  - `|` Or
  - `([A-Z\d]+-\d+)` Capture in **group 2** matching 1+ times either A-Z or a digit and `-` and 1+ digits
  - `|` Or
  - `SEI- ([\d /]+)\b` Match `SEI-` , capture in **group 3** one of the listed followed by a word boundary
- `)` Close non capture group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E2sYnI/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/DrW2lI)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"\b(?:(?:NOMEAR|d[ea]|por) ([^,]+?)(?: e Gestão)?,|([A-Z\d]+-\d+)|SEI- ([\d /]+)\b)"

filter_data_nomear = ['NOMEAR ISABELLE FERREIRA ZARONI, ID FUNCIONAL Nº\n5100796-7, para exercer, com validade a contar de 16 de novembro\nde 2020, o cargo em comissão de Assessor, símbolo DAS-7, da Sub-\nsecretaria de Concessões e Parcerias, da Secretaria de Estado de\nPlanejamento e Gestão, anteriormente ocupado por Vinicius dos San-\ntos Silva, ID Funcional n° 5108029-0. Processo nº SEI-\n1 2 0 0 0 1 / 0 1 4 6 11 / 2 0 2 0 .', 'NOMEAR KARINE MATOS DIAS, ID FUNCIONAL Nº 5092869-4 para\nexercer, com validade a contar de 16 de novembro de 2020, o cargo\nem comissão de Assessor, símbolo DAS-7, da Secretaria de Estado\nde Planejamento e Gestão, anteriormente ocupado por Amauri Ferrei-\nra do Carmo, ID Funcional nº 5099579-0. Processo nº SEI-\n1 2 0 0 0 1 / 0 1 4 6 11 / 2 0 2 0 .', 'NOMEAR ROSIONE FERNANDES DE SÁ, ID FUNCIONAL Nº\n4413710-9, para exercer, com validade a contar de 16 de novembro\nde 2020, o cargo em comissão de Assistente II, símbolo DAI-6, da\nSecretaria de Estado de Planejamento e Gestão, anteriormente ocu-\npado por Luis Henrique Ferreira de Aquino, ID Funcional nº 1914315-\n0. Processo nº SEI-120001/014825/2020.', 'NOMEAR FRANCISCO DE ASSIS PINTO CAVALCANTE para exer-\ncer, com validade a contar de 16 de novembro de 2020, o cargo em\ncomissão de Assistente II, símbolo DAI-6, da Secretaria de Estado de\nPlanejamento e Gestão, anteriormente ocupado por Edson Carneiro\nda Silva, ID Funcional nº 570136-8. Processo nº SEI-\n120001/014825/2020.']

for i in filter_data_nomear:
    result = []
    matches = re.finditer(regex, i, re.MULTILINE)
    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
        for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
            groupNum = groupNum + 1
            if match.group(groupNum) is not None:
                result.append(match.group(groupNum))
    print(result)
```

Output

```
['ISABELLE FERREIRA ZARONI', '5100796-7', '16 de novembro\nde 2020', 'Assessor', 'DAS-7', 'Sub-\nsecretaria de Concessões e Parcerias', 'Secretaria de Estado de\nPlanejamento', 'Vinicius dos San-\ntos Silva', '5108029-0']
['KARINE MATOS DIAS', '5092869-4', '16 de novembro de 2020', 'Assessor', 'DAS-7', 'Secretaria de Estado\nde Planejamento', 'Amauri Ferrei-\nra do Carmo', '5099579-0']
['ROSIONE FERNANDES DE SÁ', '4413710-9', '16 de novembro\nde 2020', 'Assistente II', 'DAI-6', 'Estado de Planejamento', 'Luis Henrique Ferreira de Aquino', 'SEI-120001']
['FRANCISCO DE ASSIS PINTO CAVALCANTE para exer-\ncer', '16 de novembro de 2020', 'Assistente II', 'DAI-6', 'Secretaria de Estado de\nPlanejamento', 'Edson Carneiro\nda Silva', '570136-8']
```

Comment: It is almost ok but having issue on the last part, please have a look on the 3rd element of the Output. I also need to get the value after SEI- as a new element eg. https://regex101.com/r/E2sYnI/2

Comment: @AlwaysSunny Perhaps like this? https://regex101.com/r/IVDHMK/1

Comment: @AlwaysSunny I see, there can be optional whitespace chars in between which you could match using `\s*` https://regex101.com/r/JHTTyT/1

Comment: @AlwaysSunny You can name all 3 groups https://regex101.com/r/9YA3Gu/1

Comment: sir I could't find any reason why on the 3rd paragraph block the regex doesn't match the full string "Secretaria de Estado de Planejamento e Gestão" . See: https://regex101.com/r/JHTTyT/1 seems new line is casuing issue but `[^,]` should match any character until `,` then why it doesn't fully match !!

Comment: @AlwaysSunny I see, the space should be a `\s`. Try it like this https://regex101.com/r/xmqGRy/1

Comment: You are a star :) #respect sir.

Comment: Sir could you please have a look on this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65094987/grab-required-field-values-from-the-paragraph-block-using-regex-in-python

Comment: @AlwaysSunny For the current question, this also might be an option to get all parts in their own  capturing group https://regex101.com/r/GKCJMB/1

Comment: Okay sir. Thanks for posting