# grab required field values from the paragraph block using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I've a text file, from that I have extracted these two paragraph block. The text example is given below.

**Text Example:**

> EXONERAR, com validade a contar de **19 de agosto de 2020**, **DE-
> NILSON DE BRITO LIMA**, ID FUNCIONAL Nº **2100423-4**, do cargo em
> comissão de **Coordenador**, símbolo **DAS-8**, da Coordenadoria de
> Gestão Centralizada de Serviços, da Superintendência de Gestão
> Centralizada, **da Subsecretaria de Logística**, **da Secretaria de
> Estado de Planejamento e Gestão**. Processo nº
> SEI-**120001/010643/2020**
>
> EXONERAR, a pedido, **NADIA NAKAMURA VIEIRA**, ID FUNCIONAL Nº
> **5099589-8**, do cargo em comissão de **Assessor Especia**l, símbolo
> **DG**, **da Secretaria de Estado de Planejamento e Gestão**. Processo nº SEI-**150001/004627/2020**
>
> EXONERAR, com validade a contar de **26 de novembro de 2020**,
> **BRUNO RAFAEL ROCHA COSTA**, ID FUNCIONAL Nº **5108093-1**, do cargo em comissão de **Assessor**, símbolo **DAS-7**, **da Assessoria de
> Planejamento e Gestão**, da Presidência, da Superintendência de Des-
> portos do Estado do Rio de Janeiro - SUDERJ, da Secretaria de Es- tado
> de Esporte, **Lazer e Juventude**. Processo nº SEI-
> **3 0 0 0 0 2 / 0 0 0 4 11 / 2 0 2 0** .
>
> EXONERAR, com validade a contar de **16 de novembro de 2020**,
> **LUIS HENRIQUE FERREIRA DE AQUINO**, ID FUNCIONAL Nº
> **1914315-0**, do cargo em comissão de **Assistente II**, símbolo **DAI-6**, da
> **Secretaria de Estado de Planejamento e Gestão**. Processo nº SEI**120001/014825/2020**:

From the above text block I want to grab the **bold** values only from each paragraph as a individual row.

**What I have tried**:

```
r"\b(?:(?:EXONERAR|d[ae]|por|símbolo)\s([^,]+?)(?: e Gestão)?,|\b(?!SEI\b)([A-Z\d]+-\s*\d+)|SEI-\s*([\d /]+)\b)"
```

**My Current Output:**

https://regex101.com/r/FCimoW/1

My current output is almost OK but having issue to not matching all the required parts e.g CAPITALIZED name part.

Comment: Perhaps like this? https://regex101.com/r/gpbqU9/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the bold uppercase parts, you can add an alternation, matching 1 or more uppercase words separated by a whitespace char or a hyphen and that end with a comma.

```
\b([A-Z]+(?:[\s-]+[A-Z]+)+(?=,)
```

[Regex demo for the full pattern](https://regex101.com/r/gDCRur/1)

Comment: `[A-Z]+` It is capturing the CAPITALIZED name but not the international characters. See: https://regex101.com/r/wqAaSg/1

Comment: @AlwaysSunny Try it like this using `\p{Lu}`  https://regex101.com/r/7iNy7o/1

Comment: may be it is not valid in python, getting error `sre_constants.error: bad escape \p at position 113`

Comment: added `\` before that like `\\p` but it is now creating issue with capturing on python

Comment: I am sorry, that does not work indeed in Python. It does work when you install the PyPi regex module. You can check [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187349/python-regex-for-unicode-capitalized-words) to match uppercase chars in python. Or you can add the specific ones to the character class that you want to match.

Comment: Please don't be. I've installed that **regex** package and it is working now. Thanks for the link. Earlier I saw that link but not sure will it work for me or not. But when you advised I used it and it is working as per my requirements. Thanks a million :)